# css menu jerkiness

Tags: html, css, styles

HTML:

```
<div style="padding-bottom:3px;background:transparent; color:white!important; float:left; margin-right:20px; line-height:42px;">
    <span class="linkcontainer">
        <a class="hardlink" style="padding:0 10px;" href="http://hronline">HROnline</a>
    </span>
    <span class="linkcontainer">
        <a class="hardlink" style="padding:0 10px; " href="http://hronline/ec">Employee Center</a>
    </span>
    <span class="linkcontainer">
        <a class="hardlink" style="padding:0 10px; " href="http://hronline/businesscommunities">Business Communities</a>
    </span>
    <span class="linkcontainer">
        <a class="hardlink" style="padding:0 10px;" href="http://hronline/internalservices">Internal Services</a>
    </span>
    <span class="linkcontainer">
        <a class="hardlink" style="padding:0 10px;" href="http://hronline/policiesprocedures">Policies&procedures</a>
    </span>
    <span class="linkcontainer">
        <a class="hardlink" style="padding:0 10px;" href="http://hronline/qualitybestpractices">Best Practices</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hardlink {
    color: #FFF !important;
}      
.hardlink:hover{
    background:url("/_layouts/images/bgximg.png") repeat-x -0px -489px; 
    background-color:#21374c; 
    border:1px solid #5badff;
    display:inline-block; 
    line-height:20px;
}
```

What is causing the whole div jerky behavior on hovering over each link?

Comment: make a demo on jsfiddle please

Comment: It is considered bad practice to use inline CSS as well as the use of `!important`

Comment: I stuck the above in a JSFiddle and can't reproduce in Chrome.

Comment: I thought you were going to complain that the css menu was being rude...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding a `border` on `:hover`. To fix the issue - just add a transparent border to normal state as well  [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mbeQk/)

```css
.hardlink {
    color: #fff !important;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```